# Sending multiple products in a order data to Google sheets only sends the first product. Why?

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce, webhooks

I must admit that I don´t have much experience so I tried my best so far-

I made a webhook on my woocommerce store and made a script on google apps to export new order data directly to spreadsheet.

The script partly works but the problem is that when there are more products in order it only exports one row and ignores the rest - so the order ID is correct the name of customer is exported but just 1 of his products from his order is exported to spreadsheet, second problem is that product ID is wrong.

The script is below:

```
    //this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var order_number = myData.number;
  var shipping_company = myData.shipping.company;
  var shipping_method = myData.shipping_lines[0].method_title;
  var customer_note = myData.customer_note;
  var shipping_lastname = myData.shipping.last_name;
  
  var lineitems=""
  for (i in myData.line_items)
  {
    var product_id = myData.line_items[i].product_id;
    var quantity = myData.line_items[i].quantity;
  
  }

  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("export");
  sheet.appendRow([order_number,product_id,customer_note,shipping_method,shipping_lastname,shipping_company,quantity,lineitems]);
}
```

[image: screenshot of google sheet]

on the sheet there is one order - which actually has 3 products in the order but only one was exported, also product ID is 4135 and correct should be 4137.

If anyone has any feedback for me I would be very happy for any help, thanks.

Comment: So, I'm not going to debug the whole thing, but your for loop isn't done correctly. Have you tried just moving the place where you append the rows into the for loop, so you're doing it more than once?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community! Would you be able to edit your original question and add the result of a `console.log(myData)` after the line `var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);`. This is so that we can see an example of the structure of the JSON that you receive. Or post an example of the structure of the JSON data your receive. With this information it will be possible to see where the problem is. Let me know if you have any questions. (please redact/sanitize any sensitive information before posting it).

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for the helpful tips - I changed the looping and I also realized that I was exporting product_id but in fact what I was looking for variation_id.

Here is the finished code I hope it will help someone:

```
    //this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
 
var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
    var order_number = myData.number;
    var shipping_company = myData.shipping.company;
    var shipping_method = myData.shipping_lines[0].method_title;
    var customer_note = myData.customer_note;
    var shipping_lastname = myData.shipping.last_name;
 
  var lineitems=""
  for (i in myData.line_items)
  {
    var variation_id = myData.line_items[i].variation_id;
    var quantity = myData.line_items[i].quantity;
    var product_items      = variation_id; 
    var lineitems =lineitems+product_items;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("export");
  sheet.appendRow([order_number,variation_id,customer_note,shipping_method,shipping_lastname,shipping_company,quantity]);
      
  }
  
 }
```